# How to create a Bitmap for Pneu Alpha function : ERROR invalid Bitmap Format. Select 16 or 256 Colors bitmap only

Tags: image, bitmap, image-conversion

Inside Pneu Alpha program, you can define you own function and you can also add some icons:

- when the function is called
- when it is not

The problem is that I don't know how to create this icon. I tried to make it in `Paint` and also in `Drawio` and convert it online intro `bitmap` format. When I try to load the picture into the program, the following error message appears  `ERROR invalid Bitmap Format. Select 16 or 256 Colors bitmap only`.

What should I do?

Also I didn't find anything related to the `with` or `height` of this bitmap image.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what Pneu Alpha is, but based on the error message you need to save the bitmap in 16 or 256 color mode. Use a more advanced image editor like Photoshop or GIMP (free) (you can just import the bmp you have, no need to start from scratch) and export the bitmap with the required format.

Comment: I didn't succed, Does it exist somewhere a standard bitmap format ? I would like to see a pictogram that works.

Comment: try save with 8-bit encoding

Comment: also try indexed mode